# How to find all records that refer to certain record by foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

How to find all records that refer to certain given record by foreign keys?

Obviously postgres do this job when populate UPDATE or DELETE action, but I need take custom action.

I guess "pg_constraint" relation can be analyzed, but maybe exists more straightforward method?

For simplicity let we know attribute to which records refer - "id"=7 and relation - "product", so more specific:

How to find all records  (in all relations) that refer by foreign keys to record "product"."id"= 7 ?

Comment: This is a bit of a FAQ, have you searched for prior answers? how to find all rows that refer to a given ID, etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger I need much more than find all rows that refer to given ID

I need:
1. Find all relations that have foreign keys that refer to given colum (ID) of given relation ("product")
2. Find all rows in all results from step 1. That have in referenced column specific value (7)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that is differers significantly from the usual questions about db-wide search. In any case the principle is the same - identify the FK relationships from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` then for each use PL/PgSQL to do a dynamic query with `EXECUTE` and `format(...)`

Comment: I would look into information_schema to see if that has the information as it changes much less than pg_catalog between major postgres versions. also it uses human_readable names not oids `information_schema.referential_constraints` seems to be the apropriate table

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a recursive function to delete records, you pass in the schema, table, and key data and  it will recursively delete-- of course, you could modify this to do anything, and it doesn't have to be recursive. The keys do have to be able to be represented as text and be single columns though.

```
create or replace function delete_cascade(p_schema varchar, p_table varchar, p_key varchar, p_recursion varchar[] default null)
 returns integer as $$
declare
    rx record;
    rd record;
    v_sql varchar;
    v_recursion_key varchar;
    recnum integer;
    v_primary_key varchar;
    v_rows integer;
begin
    recnum := 0;
    select ccu.column_name into v_primary_key
        from
        information_schema.table_constraints  tc
        join information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name and ccu.constraint_schema=tc.constraint_schema
        and tc.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
        and tc.table_name=p_table
        and tc.table_schema=p_schema;

    for rx in (
        select kcu.table_name as foreign_table_name, 
        kcu.column_name as foreign_column_name, 
        kcu.table_schema foreign_table_schema,
        kcu2.column_name as foreign_table_primary_key
        from information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
        join information_schema.table_constraints tc on tc.constraint_name=ccu.constraint_name and tc.constraint_catalog=ccu.constraint_catalog and ccu.constraint_schema=ccu.constraint_schema 
        join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu on kcu.constraint_name=ccu.constraint_name and kcu.constraint_catalog=ccu.constraint_catalog and kcu.constraint_schema=ccu.constraint_schema
        join information_schema.table_constraints tc2 on tc2.table_name=kcu.table_name and tc2.table_schema=kcu.table_schema
        join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu2 on kcu2.constraint_name=tc2.constraint_name and kcu2.constraint_catalog=tc2.constraint_catalog and kcu2.constraint_schema=tc2.constraint_schema
        where ccu.table_name=p_table  and ccu.table_schema=p_schema
        and TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
        and tc2.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
)
    loop
        v_sql := 'select '||rx.foreign_table_primary_key||' as key from '||rx.foreign_table_schema||'.'||rx.foreign_table_name||'
            where '||rx.foreign_column_name||'='||quote_literal(p_key)||' for update';
        --raise notice '%',v_sql;
        --found a foreign key, now find the primary keys for any data that exists in any of those tables.
        for rd in execute v_sql
        loop
            v_recursion_key=rx.foreign_table_schema||'.'||rx.foreign_table_name||'.'||rx.foreign_column_name||'='||rd.key;
            if (v_recursion_key = any (p_recursion)) then
                --raise notice 'Avoiding infinite loop';
            else
                --raise notice 'Recursing to %,%',rx.foreign_table_name, rd.key;
                recnum:= recnum +dallas.delete_cascade(rx.foreign_table_schema::varchar, rx.foreign_table_name::varchar, rd.key::varchar, p_recursion||v_recursion_key);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    begin
    --actually delete original record.
    v_sql := 'delete from '||p_schema||'.'||p_table||' where '||v_primary_key||'='||quote_literal(p_key);
    execute v_sql;
    get diagnostics v_rows= row_count;
    --raise notice 'Deleting %.% %=%',p_schema,p_table,v_primary_key,p_key;
    recnum:= recnum +v_rows;
    exception when others then recnum=0;
    end;

    return recnum;
end;
$$
language PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is very close to what I need. I am right, than your function is alternative realization of one-field FOREIGN KEY constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE rule?